# How to improve terrible stereo_image_proc quality

Tags: stere-image-proc

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are there any other documented techniques for improving the quality of the disparity image generated by stereo_image_proc aside from what's documented in the [wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/stereo_image_proc)?

Following [the tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/stereo_image_proc/Tutorials/ChoosingGoodStereoParameters), I spent several hours tweaking the parameters, but I found it nearly impossible to get any kind of decent quality. Any kind of surface with uniform texture either appeared as flat gray or as a constantly changing jumble of colors. Objects with a distinct texture came out the best, but even they were still barely recognizable.

[image: image description]

[image: image description]

[image: image description]

[image: image description]

Is this the best quality I should reasonably expect from a stereo camera using cheap USB webcams, or is there any way I can improve the quality?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/209044/how-to-improve-terrible-stereo_image_proc-quality/) by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 940 on 2015-05-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2015-05-12**:
stereo vision has a history of having trouble with untextured surfaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Uniform texture less surfaces cannot be used for stereo vision because the basic principle of stereo vision is to match image segments captured with both cameras from the object to calculate the disparity. This requires matchable textures!

I think the bottom result is yet quite good if you use a cheap usb comsumer camera! Shaded regions, or not matchable parts in your image is something you will always have to deal with when analysing stereo images...

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2015-05-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1